# How to run a php application without connecting to the database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to run a PHP application on my local server, I have a dump file for the database. However i am unable to create the database. I have tried running the application on the local server without configuring the database but I got the error shown in the image below. I am new to PHP and all an any help would be appreciated.

image url is:

[image]

Comment: Well you need to comment or take out every command related to the database which can lead to your application won't run or do not show anything right. I would recommend you to install php on your local machine and test it. Also please remove one of the tags sql-server or mysql.

Comment: Why are you not able to create the database? MySQL server is easy to install on almost any server and restoring the database would be far easier than trying to modify the application. Would the application even be useful without the database?

Comment: @benjamin I have a database dump file which i should use to create the database,however it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

PHP as such has no problems running without sql database backend, but that is not necessarily true about PHP applications. The application you are trying to run seems to be tightly dependent on sql database, so you won't be able to run it.

First, solve your database creation issue, then go back to the PHP application.

Comment: can you help me with the database issue? I have tried importing it using phpmyadmin, however it is returning errors.Been battling with this allday.

Comment: ok, so I was able to restore the database in the phpmyadmmin panel. now how do i connect/run both, and run the application?

Comment: @segdavids Read the installation instructions that come with the application.

Comment: it have the sourcecodes i want to review, so im not installing it, i want to run it bt it keeps giving me the error abov

Comment: You want to run it but not install it? Try to read it out loud.

Comment: youre not getting me. IT doesnt  come with an installation instruction. I have the php codes and database script, i want to run the php app after creating a database using the script. Now i have the database but i keep getting an error when i try to run the app